# Event listening for input with autocomplete on

Tags: html, autocomplete, event-handling

I have a  tag. So if one double clicks on it with a mouse the list appears and they can click on one to select a email.

My question is..
What event of the input tag should i listen to, so that this input method is captured ?

Answer (score 0):

ondblclick="myFunction()"--for doubleclick
onclick="myFunction()"--single click

to differentiate single click event and double click need to use a timeout ,to check if there is an another click after the first click.